# Do Apache Camel and Apache Airflow overlap and how do they compare?

Tags: apache-camel, etl, airflow

We are currently using [Apache-Camel](https://camel.apache.org/index.html) for [ETL](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/ETL.asp), that is, we take daily/weekly/monthly exports from various databases, perform needed actions and then publish the results somewhere for other databases to ingest.

Recently i saw a talk on [Apache-Airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/), and it seems to me that it can do the work Camel is doing only easier. By easier i mean it looks like it would be more self-documenting and therefore easier to maintain. Am i correct? And why are there no comparisons between the two, like there are between [Camel and Mule](https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/mule-vs-camel-comparison)?

Answer (score 3):

Apache Camel and Apache Airflow were written for different purposes. The former as a Enterprise Integration Framework, the latter as a platform to programmatically author, schedule and monitor workflows, this is why they are not generally compared side-by-side.

Apache Camel *can* be used for ETL: think of ETL as a process integrating the operational DB and the datawarehouse, and think of each step in the ETL data-processing process as a message.

Would it be easier to perform the task we are doing now, if we changed to Airflow? Well, generally how well suited a framework is for a specific company's needs depends on how things are set up on site. In our case we have chosen for Java and we want our processes to run on windows machines and on linux. The comparison then becomes:

- Camel's main advantages are that it we are already using it, it's Java, and there is even a Spring boot auto-configuration.
  The main disadvantages are that it is hard to maintain: understanding what exactly happens when and why, is hard. This is not directly caused by the features Camel has as a Enterprise Integration Framework, but because it is not tailored to simplify workflows.
- Airflow is specifically written with scheduling interdependent jobs in mind, it even has a GUI to simplify this task. 
  For us it would require additional installations and it may not work with our Java-witten jobs out-of-the-box (i know that it is possible to [call java](http://baojie.org/blog/2014/06/16/call-java-from-python/) from python, but this just adds more complexity).

For my needs i'm going to explore other options and maybe just leave things the way they are.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of problem(s) you are looking to solve.  Apache Camel is an enterprise integration framework that implements well-known, accepted Enterprise Integration Patterns to provide specific solutions to types of [well known problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns).

Apache Airflow does not implement these integration patterns and therefore would be less useful in solving these specific types of problems.

From my experience with Camel, it is often misused as a generic platform to solve non enterprise-integration problems, which leads to dealing with the unnecessary overhead and constraints of the framework.

Using your ETL problem as an example, I would think that Apache Camel would be unnecessary unless you were doing some form of [Message Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns#Message_Router) or [Message Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns#Message_Transformation) of the data that would warrant/benefit from using an integration solution such as Camel.  The solutions that Apache Camel offers for these well-known integration problems are the real benefit to using Apache Camel over another tool or doing it by hand.

**TLDR**; To answer your question, Apache Camel is an Enterprise Integration Framework for solving specific types of integration problems and Apache Airflow is not.  That is likely why there is no comparison between the two - they are apples and oranges, in a sense.

While you may be able to do some of the same things in both, Apache Camel will also have complex integration solutions out of the box that Airflow won't.

Comment: Apples and oranges are totally different things when you're baking a cake, but they're pretty much interchangeable when you just want something healthy to stick in your lunchbox. ETL can be done with both Camel and Airflow, I understand that Camel has loads of features that dont apply to our task, and that some of the problems we are experiencing could be aliviated if we used a more suitable tool. I've tried to put this in an answer.

Comment: My personal opinion is to avoid Camel like the plague, unless you want endless headaches and frustration when doing simple things that can be done in a quarter of the time and pain without it (JMS, SFTP, JDBC, HTTP, SOAP, File handling, etc).  Just my $.02 from 2 years of Enterprise Camel use.  I would choose any other library (or even hand roll it) before using Camel for the aforementioned items if I had a choice.  If you also want robust unit test coverage, avoid avoid avoid unless you're willing to spend a lifetime figuring out how to unit test 'routes' and working through Camel quirks.

Comment: Fair enough, what would in your opinion be the simplest approach to file-handling as part of ETL that works well with java and is platform independent?

Comment: @Ivana For platform independent file handling, I have found that the JDK  built-in Files API works excellent, as it automatically creates native calls to the OS's system libraries depending on the OS in use.  For example, Files.delete(Path myPath) will work on both Windows and Linux.  Is this the type of file-handling you are referring to?